# Pictures and shapes like lines change its position randomly when in the read-only mode

Tags: microsoft-word, read-only

In MS Word Professional Plus 2013: pictures and shapes like lines change position randomly when in read-only mode.

I anchored them but still when opening the file read-only they are out of place.

Comment: Are they, perhaps, in different locations depending on whether you're in Protected View? It's known to mess with the arrangement of floaty things.

Comment: Thank you but I'am not sure if I know what you mean.Also i realized that as I reduced the margins, in ready-only view the paragraphs are also changing..

Answer (score 1):

Without having the Word file in front of my to see exactly how it behaves, I found the information [here](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T010837_Pictures_Move_on_their_Own.html) very detailed in explaining how to anchor images and format their layout.

1. Select the image in the Word doc
2. Select Layout Options
3. Select "Fix position on page" and then "See more..."
4. Ensure the Lock Anchor checkbox is selected and the "Move object with text" checkbox is not selected

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please include the relevant parts of the article in your answer in case the link breaks.

Comment: thank you but the "anchor" in locked and "move with text" is not. I think it's because I reduced margins - the paragraphs also changed to fit the margins of read-only view

Answer (score 0):

I guess one needs to change the "layout view" to "paper layout" instead of "column layout" and everything is on place - in the ready-only doc.

Answer (score 0):

This is "by design", [according to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2755123). It seems like they designed Read mode to work well for large blocks of text, but not so much for documents with pictures, shapes or text frames in them. In such cases, they recommend that you switch to another viewing mode:

> **Cause**
>   This behavior is by design. In Read mode, text is resized
>   according to the zoom settings. However, shapes, pictures, and text
>   boxes are resized so that you can read the text more easily.
>   Additionally, some text wrapping options affect the layout of objects
>   in Read mode.
>
> **Workaround**
>   To work around the issue, view the document
>   by using different zoom settings. Or, view the document in Print
>   Layout view.